# Can someone help me? Need out output name beginning with"A" from a string[]. And ignore case

Tags: c#, arrays, string

This is all i have. This one has confused me completely:P

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] NameArray = new string[] { "Joe", "Allen", "Martin", "Gill", "anne"};


        if (NameArray.Contains("a"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(NameArray);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you're trying to do here. But if you're looking to do something with *each* item in an array, you'll need a loop...

Comment: In fact, code you've provided even will not be compiled. So how is it intended to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using linq following way:

```
 string[] NameArray = new string[] { "Joe", "Allen", "Martin", "Gill", "anne" };

 var result = NameArray.Where(x => x.StartsWith("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

[EXAMPLE WORKING FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0r4Bz9)

Comment: thanks, i was trying it this way and it wouldnt work with ignore case!

            bool a = Array.Exists(NameArray, element => element.StartsWith("A"));